# Delphi Visual FMX Component

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm trying to create (at first) a simple FMX Component.
The goal is to have a label inside the component and when I click the label to respond to his internal onclick event.

```
const
  _MS_Color_Transparent_Buttons    = claWhite;
  _MS_Color_Light_Background       = claWhite;
  _MS_Color_Dark_Background        = $FF1F2222;
  _MS_Color_Medium_Dark_Background = $FF3D454C;
  _MS_Color_Active_Selection       = $FF0281FD;
  _MS_Color_Separation_Lines       = $FFE1E0E0;

type
  TPosItemLayout = class(TLayout)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    LayMarker        : TLayout;
    rectMarker       : TRectangle;
    labelDescription : TLabel;

    procedure ToggleComponent(Sender : TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy;                    override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
  end;

constructor TPosItemLayout.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  Self.ClipChildren := True;
  Self.Parent       := AOwner as TFmxObject;
  Self.Position.X   := 0;
  Self.Height       := 153;
  Self.HitTest      := True;

  LayMarker            := TLayout.Create(Self);
  LayMarker.Parent     := Self;
  LayMarker.Position.X := 0;
  LayMarker.Position.Y := 0;
  LayMarker.Height     := 153;
  LayMarker.Width      := 3;
  LayMarker.Align      := TAlignLayout.Left;
  LayMarker.HitTest    := True;

//rectMarker
  rectMarker              := TRectangle.Create(LayMarker);
  rectMarker.Parent       := LayMarker;
  rectMarker.Position.X   := 0;
  rectMarker.Position.Y   := 0;
  rectMarker.Height       := 153;
  rectMarker.Width        := 3;
  rectMarker.Fill.Color   := _MS_Color_Active_Selection;
  rectMarker.Fill.Kind    := TBrushKind.Solid;
  rectMarker.Stroke.Color := _MS_Color_Active_Selection;
  rectMarker.Stroke.Kind  := TBrushKind.None;
  rectMarker.Align        := TAlignLayout.Client;
  rectMarker.HitTest      := True;

//lbFirstDecription - Parent LayDescription
  labelDescription                         := TLabel.Create(Self);
  labelDescription.Parent                  := Self;
  labelDescription.Position.Y              := 8;
  labelDescription.Height                  := 23;
  labelDescription.Align                   := TAlignLayout.Horizontal;
  labelDescription.StyledSettings          := labelDescription.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.FontColor, TStyledSetting.Size];
  labelDescription.FontColor               := claBlack;
  labelDescription.TextSettings.Font.Size  := 16;
  labelDescription.TextSettings.HorzAlign  := TTextAlign.Leading;
  labelDescription.TextSettings.VertAlign  := TTextAlign.Center;
  labelDescription.Text                    := 'Description';
  labelDescription.WordWrap                := False;
  labelDescription.HitTest                 := True;
  labelDescription.OnClick                 := ToggleComponent;
end;

destructor TPosItemLayout.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TPosItemLayout.ToggleComponent(Sender: TObject);
begin
  showmessage('toggle');
end;
```

in my test application i click on then label but nothing happend.

i have try to play around hittest but nothing.

what i miss?

how can I do to make it work?

EDIT 1
I have change the code. the onclick on the original code is hidden :(
the following code is act semibizar.

```
type 
  TPosItemLayout = class(TLayout)
  private
    { Private declarations }
  protected
    { Protected declarations }
    imgDelete : TButton;

    procedure ToggleComponent(Sender : TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
    constructor Create(AOwner: TComponent); override;
    destructor  Destroy;                    override;
  published
    { Published declarations }
    property btnDelete  : TButton read imgDelete;
  end;

procedure Register;

implementation

procedure Register;
begin
  RegisterComponents('Samples', [TPosItemLayout]);
end;

{ TPosItemLayout }

constructor TPosItemLayout.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
var ImgStream : TResourceStream;
begin
  inherited;
  Self.ClipChildren := True;
  Self.Position.X   := 0;
  Self.Height       := 153;
  Self.Width        := 400;

  imgDelete                := TButton.Create(Self);
  imgDelete.Parent         := Self;
  imgDelete.Width          := 60;
  imgDelete.Height         := 24;
  imgDelete.HitTest        := True;
  imgDelete.Align          := TAlignLayout.Right;
  imgDelete.Text           := 'E';
  imgDelete.OnClick        := ToggleComponent;
end;

destructor TPosItemLayout.Destroy;
begin

  inherited;
end;

procedure TPosItemLayout.ToggleComponent(Sender: TObject);
begin
  imgDelete.Text := 'Click';
end;
```

at design time it create the button and align right
but at run time 2 button are crated .. one respond to click and do what is intend to do .. the other doesent do nothing.

how to track this problem ?

this messup is created by the IDE. If i change the text on the button and close / open the project another button appear. change the text on the new button close/open another is created. and so on.

Comment: Surely you should not be setting the control's  parent in the constructor. The streaming framework does that.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would be concerned that rectMarker could be swallowing the mouse clicks. I would try either making the parent of labelDescription to be rectMarker, or setting HitTest for rectMarker to False.

Comment: I'm more than sure I have to set the parent. no "internal" component is visible if I dont do that.

Comment: @PopaOvidiu-Razvan I think David meant setting self.parent was unnecessary. Setting the other two parents is necessary.

Comment: ah. ok. you are correct.

Comment: I said control rather than sub-control.

Comment: on VCL the same code is working properly, so i belive is only FMX related.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the *SetSubComponent* feature known from VCL does not work for FMX. As shown in the mentioned duplicate setting `imgDelete.Stored := false` is the way to go. In addition, *SetSubComponent* doesn't play nicely with the Stored = false setting either.

Comment: I believe that this does work. This has always been the answer every time the question has been asked before.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, actually it doesn't work! Seems the SubComponent feature is completely broken in FMX.

Comment: OK, we'll I guess you've got this answer to update and an answer to add at the dupe!

Answer (score 1):

This is because The streaming process also creates the button. You need to mark the button (and any other component you intend to create) with the stored FALSE attribute like this:

```
property btnDelete  : TButton read imgDelete; stored FALSE;
```

This will stop the button being stored (and hence reloaded). But I don't think this relates to your original problem (although it might seem like it does..). Please see my earlier comment for what I think that is.

Comment: I am confused about the questions as you seem to be asking two different things. For your initial question: 1. Not sure you need the clip children 2. As people say you don't need the self.parent assignment and 3. (To answer your question) the hittest of your component is true, which means that the label never receives any click events. Asa